# Disable Firebase Sign up in AuthUI for Web

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authui for web as documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui

My problem is, that I want to disable the sign-up for new users in my webapp. But already signed up users should still be able to login.

Also the sign up from my android app should still work.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Might help: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/99#issuecomment-359443621

Comment: @Mohsen thanks, but actually my problem is even more complicated because I want users to be able to sign up from my android app but not from the web app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for that has been added in version [v4.8.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/releases/tag/v4.8.0) as stated in this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/99#issuecomment-794537000).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
signInOptions: { provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, disableSignUp: {status: true, adminEmail: "johndoe@mail.com", helpLink: (string|undefined) }
```

This will show something like this:

[image]

There are more options on  the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configure-email-provider)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are not able to do that.  **FirebaseUI** is a prebuilt authentication UI, which has not much customisability, you have to bear with it if you want to use Firebase UI.  In this case, you could implement role based authentication to restrict new user.  For example, for new user, the user profile will be assigned a role as newUser, in the security rule, you can restrict/ deny the user with newUser role.

Another solution is to do the coding yourself (from scratch) and implement firebase authentication.

Hope this give you some idea!